# State maintenance goes wrong in minimax search on board game

Tags: java, oop, artificial-intelligence, minimax

I am working on implementing minimax on a board game but am having issues when searching the state tree. I am fairly certain it is either

1. my implementation of minimax which is wrong, or
2. the way I build my next state on which minimax will do its search, or
3. a combination of 1 and 2

I sat out writing the code for the game in the best object-oriented way I could. This is first and foremost for practice but also to try and decouple things as best as possible. But this decision has *maybe* become a bit of an obstacle for my progress with minimax because the code for the game itself has become a little convoluted. This has made debugging state in the game a little complex. However, through careful debugging I feel confident that the state of the game is maintained well when I play a game where I alternate between two human players -- i.e. I do not do any minimax search on the state of the game. But as soon as I invoke minimax search, then the game state start to fall apart rather quickly, as if the way I do my minimax recursion or build my next state is wrong.

Before I show the work I have done in relation to minimax I'll first introduce how the game is modeled to make sure you have the information you need. After this I will show a sample output of the game running with minimax activated. I have tried to comment the output so you can see what is going *wrong*.

Let's get to it.

The game is a board game of 3 x 4 cells like so:

```
+---+---+---+
|   |   |   | 0 <- Starting row of Black player
+---+---+---+
|   |   |   | 1
+---+---+---+
|   |   |   | 2
+---+---+---+
|   |   |   | 3 <- Starting row of Red player
+---+---+---+
  0   1   2
```

I'll introduce the classes I have constructed now. I will leave out generic code like constructors and get/set methods and only highlight important methods which change the state of the class instance.

The `Board` class is modeled in the following way:

```
public class Board
{
    public static final int ROWS = 4;
    public static final int COLUMNS = 3;
    private Cell[][] cells;

    public Board()
    {
        initialize();
    }

    private void initialize()
    {
        cells = new Cell[ROWS][COLUMNS];
        for (int row = 0; row < ROWS; row++)
        {
            for (int column = 0; column < COLUMNS; column++)
            {
                cells[row][column] = new Cell(row, column);
            }
        }
    }

    public Board getDeepCopy(State state)
    {
        Board boardCopy = new Board();

        for (int row = 0; row < ROWS; row++)
            for (int column = 0; column < COLUMNS; column++)
                boardCopy.cells[row][column] = cells[row][column].getDeepCopy(state);

        return boardCopy;
    }

    //Other generic logic
    ...
}
```

I have created a `getDeepCopy(State state)` method in a couple of the classes which I use to construct a copy of the current state of the game on which minimax will do its search, so as not to change the *real* state of the game. So this method will repeat itself in other classes, as you will see.

The `Cell` class looks like follows

```
public class Cell
{
    private String content;
    private Piece piece;
    private int row;
    private int column;

    public Cell getDeepCopy(State state)
    {
        Cell c = new Cell(row, column);
        c.content = content;
        c.piece = piece != null ? piece.getDeepCopy(state) : null;
        return c;
    }

    //Other generic logic
    ...
}
```

The `Piece` class is defined as

```
public class Piece
{
    private Point point;
    private String symbol;

    public Piece getDeepCopy(State state)
    {
        return state.getBoard().getCells()[this.getPoint().getY()][this.getPoint().getX()].getPiece();
    }

    //Other generic logic
    ...
}
```

The game has 2 players, a Red and a Black player. They each have 4 pieces available

The `Player` class looks like so:

```
public class Player
{
    private Color color;
    private int score;
    private Stack<Piece> pieces;
    private ArrayList<Piece> placedPieces;
    public static final int MAX_PIECES = 4;

    private void initializePieces()
    {
        pieces = new Stack<>();
        placedPieces = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < MAX_PIECES; i++)
        {
            pieces.push(new Piece(color.getSymbol()));
        }
    }

    public Piece getAvailablePiece()
    {
        return pieces.empty() ? null : pieces.pop();
    }

    public void returnPiece(Piece piece)
    {
        if (pieces.size() != MAX_PIECES)
        {
            pieces.push(piece);
        }
    }

    public void updatePlacedPieces(Piece piece)
    {
        if (!placedPieces.contains(piece))
            placedPieces.add(piece);
        else
            for (Piece match : placedPieces)
                if (piece.equals(match))
                    match.setPoint(piece.getPoint());

    }

    //Other generic logic
    ...
}
```

Now to the more heavy parts of the game, the game state and the minimax algorithm. All game state is represented in a `State` class as below (take note of the `getDeepCopy()` method, which I suspect is one of the main culprits)

```
public class State
{
    private int points;
    private Board board;
    private Player turn;
    private Player opponent;
    private Player redPlayer;
    private Player blackPlayer;
    private Move move;
    private State parent;
    private ArrayList<Move> availableMoves;
    private int depth;

    // Root state (s_0)
    public State(int points)
    {
        this.points = points;
        redPlayer = new Player(Color.Red);
        blackPlayer = new Player(Color.Black);
        turn = redPlayer;
        opponent = blackPlayer;
        depth = 0;
        board = new Board();
        parent = null;
    }

    // Child states from root state (s_1, s_2, ... s_n)
    public State(State parent, Move move)
    {
        this.parent = parent;
        this.move = move;
        redPlayer = parent.getRedPlayer();
        blackPlayer = parent.getBlackPlayer();
        depth = parent.depth + 1;
        points = parent.getPoints();
        board = parent.getBoard();
        passTurn(parent.getTurn());
        availableMoves = Logic.getAllMoves(this);
    }

    public void passTurn(Player lastTurn)
    {
        if (lastTurn.equals(redPlayer))
        {
            turn = blackPlayer;
            opponent = redPlayer;
        }
        else
        {
            turn = redPlayer;
            opponent = blackPlayer;
        }
        System.out.println(String.format("\nTurn: %s", turn.toString()));
    }

    public State getDeepCopy(State state, Move move)
    {
        State stateCopy = new State();
        stateCopy.move = move;
        stateCopy.parent = state.getParent();
        stateCopy.points = state.getPoints();
        stateCopy.redPlayer = state.getRedPlayer();
        stateCopy.blackPlayer = state.getBlackPlayer();
        stateCopy.turn = state.getTurn();
        stateCopy.opponent = state.getOpponent();
        stateCopy.depth = state.getDepth();
        stateCopy.board = state.getBoard().getDeepCopy(state); // Here the deep copy begins
        stateCopy.availableMoves = state.getAvailableMoves();
        return stateCopy;
    }

    //Other generic logic
}
```

The game is running in a main class called `Game` where I alternate between a human move and an AI move. All game logic is handled in a class `Logic`, with only `static` methods. This class implements the rules of the game, e.g. if a player wants to insert a piece, and is assisted by a `BoardManager` class (also only with `static` methods) which does operations on the board (placing a piece, removing a piece, etc.). So the `Logic` class holds no state, neither does the `BoardManager` class, they only modify current state based on the Game's instance of state.

Here is the `Game`class with its most important methods highlighted

```
public class Game
{
    private State state;
    private boolean playing;

    public void play() throws IOException
    {
        drawBoard();
        System.out.println(String.format("First player to make a move is %s", state.getTurn().toString()));
        playing = true;

        while (!isGameOver() && playing)
            if (isHumanPlayer())
                doHumanMove();
            else
                doAIMove();
    }

    private void doHumanMove() throws IOException
    {
        Choice choice = getChoice();

        boolean isMoveOk = false;
        Move move = null;

        switch (choice)
        {
            case INSERT:
                System.out.print("Enter cell to insert on: ");
                Point to = getPointFromUser();
                move = new Move(to, state.getRedPlayer(), Move.Type.Insert);
                isMoveOk = Logic.doMove(move, state);
                break;
            case ...
        }
        if (isMoveOk)
        {
            drawBoard();
            state = new State(state, move);
        }
    }

    private void doAIMove()
    {
        Move move = MiniMax.search(0, state, false);
        state = new State(state, move);
        drawBoard();
    }
}
```

Now to the nitty-gritty part, the minimax class. I invoke minimax using the `search()` method, as can be seen above in the `play()` method of `Game`. I then call `miniMax()` on a `depth`, the current `State` and whether the current player is the `maximizer`. I hope it is self-explanatory by looking at the code

```
public class MiniMax
{
    private static final int maxDepth = 2;

    public static Move search(int depth, State state, boolean isPlayerMaximizer)
    {
        System.out.println("Starting MiniMax search...");
        Value v = miniMax(depth, state, isPlayerMaximizer);
        return v.getMove();
    }

    private static Value miniMax(int depth, State state, boolean isPlayerMaximizer)
    {
        state.getBoard().draw();

        if (depth == maxDepth || state.getTurn().getScore() == state.getPoints())
            return getScore(state);

        if (isPlayerMaximizer)
            return getMax(depth, state);

        else
            return getMin(depth, state);
    }

    private static Value getMax(int depth, State state)
    {
        int bestScore = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        Move bestMove = null;

        state.setAvailableMoves(Logic.getAllMoves(state)); // Is this wrong?
        for (Move move : state.getAvailableMoves())
        {
            State nextState = state.getDeepCopy(state, move); // Copy of state to work on
            Logic.doMove(move, nextState);
            nextState.passTurn(nextState.getTurn());
            Value val = miniMax(depth + 1, nextState, false);

            if (val.getValue() >= bestScore)
            {
                bestScore = val.getValue();
                bestMove = move;
            }
        }

        if (bestMove != null)
            Logic.doMove(bestMove, state);

        return new Value(bestScore, bestMove);
    }

    private static Value getMin(int depth, State state)
    {
        int bestScore = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        Move bestMove = null;
        state.setAvailableMoves(Logic.getAllMoves(state));
        for (Move move : state.getAvailableMoves())
        {
            State nextState = state.getDeepCopy(state, move);
            Logic.doMove(move, nextState);
            state.passTurn(nextState.getTurn());
            Value val = miniMax(depth + 1, nextState, true);

            if (val.getValue() <= bestScore)
            {
                bestScore = val.getValue();
                bestMove = move;
            }
        }

        if (bestMove != null)
            Logic.doMove(bestMove, state);

        return new Value(bestScore, bestMove);
    }

    private static Value getScore(State state)
    {
        Player maximizer = state.getRedPlayer();
        Player minimizer = state.getBlackPlayer();

        if (state.getTurn() == maximizer && maximizer.getScore() == state.getPoints())
            return new Value(10, state.getMove());

        else if (state.getTurn() == minimizer && minimizer.getScore() == state.getPoints())
            return new Value(-10, state.getMove());

        else
            return new Value(0, state.getMove());
    }

    private static class Value {
        int value;
        Move move;

        public Value(int value, Move move) {
            this.value = value;
            this.move = move;
        }

        public Move getMove() {
            return move;
        }

        public int getValue()
        {
            return value;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a run of the game where I invoke minimax

```
Welcome!

// Initial state (human player makes a move)

+---+---+---+
|   |   |   | 0
+---+---+---+
|   |   |   | 1
+---+---+---+
|   |   |   | 2
+---+---+---+
|   |   |   | 3
+---+---+---+
  0   1   2 

First player to make a move is Red

Choose an option:
 1. Insert
 2. Diagonal move
 3. Attack
 4. Jump 
 5. Exit

Input: 1
Enter cell to insert on: 0,3
Red is trying to do a Insert move...
Red placed a piece on the board at (0, 3).

// So far so good

+---+---+---+
|   |   |   | 0
+---+---+---+
|   |   |   | 1
+---+---+---+
|   |   |   | 2
+---+---+---+
| R |   |   | 3
+---+---+---+
  0   1   2 

Turn: Black

Starting MiniMax search... // OK, time for the AI to make a move

+---+---+---+
|   |   |   | 0
+---+---+---+
|   |   |   | 1
+---+---+---+
|   |   |   | 2
+---+---+---+
| R |   |   | 3
+---+---+---+
  0   1   2 

Black is trying to do a Insert move...
Black placed a piece on the board at (0, 0).

Turn: Red

// So far so good

+---+---+---+
| B |   |   | 0
+---+---+---+
|   |   |   | 1
+---+---+---+
|   |   |   | 2
+---+---+---+
| R |   |   | 3
+---+---+---+
  0   1   2 

Black is trying to do a Insert move...
Black placed a piece on the board at (1, 0).

Turn: Red

// Black just did two moves in a row, looks like the turn is not passed on properly?
// Looks like after just 1 move with minimax the state of the game becomes wrong?

+---+---+---+
| B | B |   | 0
+---+---+---+
|   |   |   | 1
+---+---+---+
|   |   |   | 2
+---+---+---+
| R |   |   | 3
+---+---+---+
  0   1   2 

Black is trying to do a Insert move...
Black placed a piece on the board at (2, 0).

Turn: Red

// Take note that the piece inserted by black at (1, 0) no longer exists on the board below
// Does getDeepCopy() not work properly?

+---+---+---+
| B |   | B | 0
+---+---+---+
|   |   |   | 1
+---+---+---+
|   |   |   | 2
+---+---+---+
| R |   |   | 3
+---+---+---+
  0   1   2 

Black is trying to do a Diagonal move...
Black moved diagonally from (0, 0) to (1, 1)

Turn: Red

// Same thing here, now the piece at (2, 0) is gone
// But the piece which was moved from (0, 0) to (1, 1) is still there

+---+---+---+
|   |   |   | 0
+---+---+---+
|   | B |   | 1
+---+---+---+
|   |   |   | 2
+---+---+---+
| R |   |   | 3
+---+---+---+
  0   1   2 

// Console output is duplicated because the move now happened on the actual game state
Black is trying to do a Diagonal move...
Black moved diagonally from (0, 0) to (1, 1) 

// Red is trying to INSERT on a row which does not belong to Red
// Looks like the turn was not updated properly?

Red is trying to do a Insert move...
Invalid move: not starting row of Red.

Turn: Black
```

Thank you for reading this rather lengthy post. I hope I can gain some insights into what I am doing wrong so I can make this minimax search do its job properly!

Comment: I'll try to look at this more later, but my first reactions are: 1) your getDeepCopy in Piece should be just `return new Piece(point, symbol);` and you should eliminate the State argument to your non-State classes. 2) State.getDeepCopy should be static, 3) You're asking for trouble by storing information so redundantly. As a design consideration, I would either let the pieces know where they are or let the board know where the pieces are, but not both. Certainly not all three of Board, Cell, and Piece. Maybe Board could just have an array of Color objects, mostly null? (So no Cell, no Piece)

Comment: The more I think about it, the more I'm convinced that your fundamental issue here is too much information repetition. (And relatedly, too many classes) Eliminate the Piece and Cell classes. Let Board be in charge of how many pieces each player has played and whether "insert" is legal. Let players keep nothing but color and score. Don't record anything that you could recompute from other objects. Then, once you get the logic correct, you can slowly start to add spots that record some redundant information for efficiency but ONLY once you have it working at all.

Comment: @DanielMartin thank you for the comments! I initially had the `getDeepCopy()` in Piece defined like that but it caused problems in the Player class when I call `updatePlacedPieces()` due to the object ID's no longer matching. I agree with your comment about redundancy but refactoring this will take quite some doing, so I would want to keep the design as it is for now. Another reason I don't find the refactor necessary is the fact than when I play as two human players then each new state works perfectly fine, which leads me back to my original suspicion that this is a minimax issue. Thanks!